# connect to xmpp server

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

i try to connect to my xmpp server by this code

```
    final String servicename = "my server ip";  
    XMPPTCPConnection connection;


    public void Register(String userName, String password)throws XMPPException, SmackException, IOException
    {
   try{
          XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
          .setServiceName(servicename)
          .setUsernameAndPassword("admin username", "admin password")
          .setCompressionEnabled(false).build();

          connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);

          connection.connect();
          AccountManager AM = AccountManager.getInstance(connection);
          AM.createAccount(userName, password);
          connection.disconnect();
          System.out.println(":)");
     } 
     catch(XMPPException e){
          System.out.println(":(");            
     }

    }
```

all the code is in try catch but when i call this function nothing gets printed and get error.

I'm new to java but i think it is getting error from config declaration

i copy config declaration from [here](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/tcp/XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.html)

how can i fix this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally find the answer.it seems that after smack 4 you need to add some more jar files to your project and one of them that solve my problem was [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadapachehttpcomponentshttpclientjar.htm)